# Does Android 4.4 webview support CSS mask?

Tags: android, css, webview, mask, android-4.4-kitkat

On Android 4.4 *(KitKat)*, is there any reported bug regarding **-webkit-mask**?
in **Chrome** *(Nexus 10)*, the mask render **perfect**, 
but in a **Webview** *(Same tablet)*, the mask render a **black shape** instead.
I thought that the CSS render in Chrome and Webview were the same since KitKat?
I have searched alot, but didn't found anything about CSS differences between both.
Anyone have an idea or a link that can help?
Thanks